# How to add Swipe events in Starling

Tags: apache-flex, starling-framework

I am new to Starling, I want to implement swipe event in starling.
How can i add swipe event when user swipes on particular image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm only vaguely familiar with Starling; but can you create something using the touch event on the Image? http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/starling/display/DisplayObject.html#event:touch ?  Some more info here: http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/starling-and-swipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native swipe event in Starling. But there is a library for that to extend Starling.
Could this library be what you're looking for?
https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch